# How to extract sections from sourcefile and save as a separate files with gulp?

Tags: javascript, split, gulp

I have `*.source` file which contains three sections: `jade`, `js` and `scss`.

Example `materialPalette.source` file:

```
/* section jade */
  // some jade code, should be saved as materialPalette.jade
/* end jade */


/* section js */
  // js code > materialPalette.js
/* end js */


/* section scss */
  // scss code > materialPalette.scss
/* end scss */
```

How can i split `materialPalette.source` (and other *.source) into separete files for each section?
Expected functionality:

```
gulp.src('../framework/**/*.source')
// PSEUDOCODE:
// extract sections and save in the same folder as *.source files
.pipe( extract(function('jade', './FILENAME.jade')) )
.pipe( extract(function('js', './FILENAME.js')) )
.pipe( extract(function('scss', './FILENAME.scss')) );
```

Comment: I think that you have to write your own plugin for this kind of functionality https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/writing-a-plugin/README.md which is not going to be very hard activity

Answer (score 0):

There is a script for pretty close to this task:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-split-file

But i have written my own node package called SplitFile, which uses XML tags to separate sections of code and output attibute for easy defining output file location.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/splitfile